# formultario filtros php

Tags: php

boas estou a fazer uma plataforma em php com html e pedidos ajax, tenho dois anos . Sempre que mudo de ano ele mantem os dados anteriores existe alguma forma de apagar os dados que estao o datalist

Comment: Dois anos? Tão jovem e já programa em PHP? lol #MomentoDescontração. Falando sério agora, poderia melhorar a pergunta e se possível colocar o trecho do código que está com problema? Me parece que seu problema é mais com o Ajax do que com PHP. Aguardo mais informações

Comment: while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $meiovida[] = "<option value='$row[descricao]'/>"; // Format for adding options
    }
    echo json_encode($meiovida); tenho algo deste genero no php no ajax so faço o append. se usar um select não acontece.

Comment: Desculpe mas ainda não consegui visualizar seu problema, se pudesse melhorar a pergunta ajudaria bastante.

Comment: na query no sql da menos resultados.. no datalist esta a por dados relativos a query anterior

Answer (score -1):

Olá,
Não sei se entendi muito bem. Mas tu não pode dar um "vazio" usando um innerHtml = "" no elemento e remontar o datalist.